# For a new VG Mount, Why Does 'mkdir /volumeName' NOT need more detail for the file path?

Tags: linux, mount

Note:  Following assumes sudo as root

I've added a physical volume and volume group to a Linux server.
Current structure:

```
sda
|_vg1-stuff1
|_vg1-stuff2
|_vg1-stuff3
...etc...


sdb
|_vg2-stuff1
|_vg2-stuff2
|_vg2-stuff3
...etc...


sdc # new pv
|_vg3-new_vol_group
```

vgstatus vg3/new_vol_group returns:
`LV Status available`

I've run `mkfs` against `/dev/vg3/new_vol_group` and have a `blkid` for vg3.

`ls -lah /dev/vg3/new_vol_group` returns:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Mon dd hh:mm /dev/vg3/new_vol_group -> ../dm-10
```

Following my "Google homework" I should be ready to add the directory for the mount and add the entry to `/etc/fstab`.

However it's this line in my homework that I'm hung up on:

```
mkdir /volumeName # create the directory prior to mounting
```

(specifically the file path indicated "/")

Since I'm sudo'd to root, is the path '/volumeName' sufficient?
I'm trying to assure myself that with 3 phys-vols, and 3 vg's Im placing the mount directory in the proper "home."

If I attempt to "qualify" the file path it errors:

```
mkdir /dev/vg3/new_vol_group/new_vol_group
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/dev/vg3/new_vol_group/volumeName’: Not a directory
```

Why doesnt `mkdir` need a more detailed "path" for `/volumeName`?
...or what else does the question reveal I need to know?

Comment: Peregrino69 : TY for the format edits.  Been a minute since I've been over here and my formatting skills need a refresh :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction `mkdir /volumeName # create the directory prior to mounting` is for creating the directory `volumeName` on the root filesystem (`/`) to mount your volume group onto, it should not exist on the volume group itself.

If you do not want to mount to `/volumeName` then create some other directory to mount to and adjust the instructions accordingly.

Once the proper directory is created, you should be able to mount your volume group and setup your `fstab`.

Comment: GracefulRestart:  Fair enough.  Worked like a charm!  TY!!

Can I expand on my question a little more?
Is it because once I'm sudo'd to root then every beginning fwd slash (/) is a reference to the "root home" and so then I know that mkdir /volumeName is a directory available to the full server?

To date, each time Ive worked with mkdir it's been in the context of adding to an existing files system among multiple pv's and vg's, so of course it's called for the "qualified file path"

Comment: After some additional education the "root" (pun intended) of my knowledge gap was about the directory structures when qualifying the path.  I feared that /volumeName was dependent on the location I was present to at that time, so that if I was in /otherDirectory then mkdir /volumeName would create /otherDirectory/volumeName.  The single slash at the start of the path goes only to the root of the server.  So no matter where you are mkdir /volumeName will only arrive at the server root of / and can be observed by ls -lah / from anywhere on the server.